# Fancy Box and Submit Button

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have a submit button in Fancy box, but it doesn't submit when I press it. Here is my mark-up.

```
<?php print \Fuel\Core\Form::open('user/search/find/constructor'); ?>
<ul class="other-region">
    /* bunch of forms inputs and selections */
</ul>

/*The submit form outside the fancy box modal*/
<?php print \Fuel\Core\Form::submit('Submit', '絞り込む',
        array('class'=>'redBtn positionRight','title'=>'絞り込む')); ?>

<!-- Start Hidden Divs for Modal -->
<div id="buildersMoreDetails" style="display: none;">
    <h2>詳細条件</h2>
        <table class="moreDetails">
                /* Also a bunch of input forms that are inside the modal */
                <tr>
                /* Submit button inside the Modal */
            <td colspan="2">
                    <?php print \Fuel\Core\Form::submit('Submit2', '検索',
                            array('class'=>'redBtn f-right','title'=>'検索')); ?>
                </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<?php print Fuel\Core\Asset::js('jquery.fancybox.js'); ?>
<?php print Fuel\Core\Asset::css('jquery.fancybox.css'); ?>
<?php print \Fuel\Core\Form::close(); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fancybox').fancybox({
        closeBtn: false,
        helpers : {
            title : null            
        }     
    });
});
</script>
```

There must be something in the modal the cancels the Submit button. I would like to do this without resorting to Ajax, since the purpose of the submit button inside and outside the modal are the same.

Comment: Is there any form to submit?

Comment: yes, bunch of inputs and selections.